# Merge ParamConverter and BodyConverter objects on FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using the param converter to get object from url and body converter to get object form body.

This perfectly works for `GET` and `POST` methods, but I have to do it with a tricky way for an update (`PUT`):

```
/**
 * @param PowerDNSDomain                   $domain
 * @param PowerDNSRecord                   $record
 * @param PowerDNSRecord                   $updatedRecord
 * @param ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors
 *
 * @ParamConverter("updatedRecordData", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function putAction(PowerDNSDomain $domain, PowerDNSRecord $record, PowerDNSRecord $updatedRecord, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
{
    if ($validationErrors->count() > 0) {
        return $this->handleBodyValidationErrorsView($validationErrors);
    }

    $record->setName($updatedRecord->getName().'.'.$domain->getName())
           ->setContent($updatedRecord->getContent())
           ->setTtl($updatedRecord->getTtl())
           ->setPrio($updatedRecord->getPrio());

    $this->get('manager.dns')->saveRecord($record);

    return $this->view($record);
}
```

In a nutshell, I have to retrieve two `PowerDNSDomain` object (one from the URL, one from the body) and update **each fields** manually.

This is overkill, isn't it?

The preferred way would be to have a method signature like this:

```
public function putAction(PowerDNSDomain $domain, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
```

Where the `PowerDNSDomain $domain` would be the result of the body converter object merged into the param converter one.

In this case, I will just have to get validation errors and save the object.

How can I make this possible ? :-)

Related configuration:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
        validate: true
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
    view:
        formats:
            xml:  false
            json: true
            rss:  false
            yml:  true
        view_response_listener: force
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api/', priorities: ['json', 'yml'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true } # FOSRest should not handle other routes than API
        media_type:
            enabled: true
```

Possibly related issue: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/1238